# How to fetch specific amount of users using github api v3?

Tags: api, github, github-api, github-api-v3

When I want to fetch github users using this api: `https://api.github.com/users` it gives me back exactly 46 users. How can I fetch e.g. just 10 of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add [the `per_page` directive](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/traversing-with-pagination/#changing-the-number-of-items-received) in your API URL

> By passing the per_page parameter, you can specify how many items you want each page to return, up to 100 items.
>   Let's try asking for 10 items about `addClass`:
>
> ```
> curl -I "https://api.github.com/search/code?q=addClass+user:mozilla&per_page=10"
> ```

Apply the same idea to `api.github.com/users`

The first "page" of result would be 10 users.